# Is there a formula for the sum of absolute eigenvalues in terms of matrix elements?

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, matrix-decomposition

Given a symmetric matrix $X \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$.
We know the following:
trace$(X) = \sum_{i=1}^n x_{ii} = \sum_{i=1}^n \lambda_i$
where $x_{ii}$ is the $i$th element on the diagonal of $X$, and ${\lambda_i}$ are the eignevalues of $X$.

If we cannot guarantee that $X$ is positive-semidefinite, is there a way to write $\sum_{i=1}^n| \lambda_i |$ in terms of entries of $X$, and perhabs other slack variables?